# Radeon X1300 acceleration

Tags: windows, graphics-card, performance, amd-radeon, acceleration

I've just bought a Samsung XL2370 with a native resolution of 1920x1080. Should a Radeon X1300 be capable of shifting around windows on a screen that size? Because maximising and minimising windows, scrolling in Firefox and VS2008 seems very slow and jerky.

Does the Radeon X1300 have any hardware accelearation? My old display was only 1028x768 and I never noticed any problems.

Maybe is it time to buy a new graphics card?

Comment: What are the other specs of the machine?

Answer (score 1):

It could be more than just your graphic card that is giving you `slow / jerky` reaction time.  Next time should give your full computer specs, for a much better answer.

However the X1300 alone is a 'low level' card, but for what you describe it should do the job just fine (even dual display - depending on connectors).

I would suspect something like CPU + Ram being the bottleneck here.

Comment: Or software, virus scanner running... more detail required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working only with developer tools like VS2008 and your UI is not AERO from Vista or win7 - I think you can do with current card.